# Что не так с заменой str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

есть ряд параметров типа `'.htm#1','htm#2', 'htm#3', 'htm#4', 'htm#5', 'htm#6', 'htm#7', 'htm#8', 'htm#9', 'htm#10', 'htm#11' ,'htm#12'...`
нужно к первым 9-ти добавить "0", чтобы все были двухзначные `('.htm#01','htm#02', 'htm#03', ..., 'htm#09', 'htm#10', 'htm#11' ,'htm#12'...)`
Пытаюсь через str_replace:
`str_replace(array('#1','#2', '#3'..., '#9'), array('#01', '#02', '#03',..., '#09'), $text)`
Меняется благополучно, но не только у первых 9-ти, а добавляется "0" и к следующим: `htm#011`, и дальше.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вопрос решен другим способом, спасибо!
P.S. Понравились минуса на мой ответ - наверное я решение неправильное дал или обидел кого? Ну да ладно, не смертельно

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в `#11` входит подстрока `#1` очевидно. И в других аналогично.

Придётся  применить регулярку и preg_replace

---

Попробуйте так:

```
$arr = ['.htm#1', '.htm#2', '.htm#3', '.htm#11', '.htm#112', '.htm#21'];
$newArr = array_map(function($item) {
    $pattern = '/(.*?#)(\d{1})$/i';
    $replacement = '${1}0${2}';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $item);
}, $arr);

print_r($newArr);


Array
(
    [0] => .htm#01
    [1] => .htm#02
    [2] => .htm#03
    [3] => .htm#11
    [4] => .htm#112
    [5] => .htm#21
)
```

Comment: Да пробовал через preg_replace(array('/#1/','/#2/', '/#3/', '/#4/', '/#5/', '/#6/', '/#7/', '/#8/', '/#9/'), array('#01', '#02', '#03', '#04', '#05', '#06', '#07', '#08', '#09'), $text) - результат тот же. И с preg_replace(/#1|#2|#3.../)

Comment: @Siamajor попробуй то что в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо! Но не пошло. Я плюнул на это дело и просто изменил якоря на страницах через регулярку, избавившись таким образом от этих изменений. Еще раз спасибо!